# how to click on a multi word dynamic button with cucumber and capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Trying to write a test which involves clicking on a button with two words as shown in the code below.

Click_on("More Filters") does not work as the button consists of distinct words and when clicked the button changes to "less Filters". 
None of the css selectors seems to work or the Xpath.

The filter can be seen in the [link](https://www.redfin.com/city/10940/CA/Long-Beach/filter/sort=lo-distance,viewport=33.82154881308594:33.718551986914065:-118.12507494921876:-118.26240405078126,no-outline,geo-address=Long+Beach%0C+CA%0C+USA)

```
<button class="button Button wideSidepaneFilterButton v3 compact text" type="button" tabindex="0" data-rf-test-id="filterButton" data-reactid="133">
  <span data-reactid="134">
    <span class="wideSidepaneMoreText" data-reactid="135">More</span>
    <span class="wideSidepaneFiltersText" data-reactid="136">Filters</span>
    <svg class="SvgIcon rfSvg show-less showMoreIcon rotate" data-reactid="137">
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no actual space between the two words so try

```
click_button(“MoreFilters”)
```

The following code shows that it works as long as you are actually using selenium, as indicated by your tags, for your tests

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome)
session.visit "https://www.redfin.com/city/10940/CA/Long-Beach/filter/sort=lo-distance,viewport=33.82154881308594:33.718551986914065:-118.12507494921876:-118.26240405078126,no-outline,geo-address=Long+Beach%0C+CA%0C+USA"

session.click_button('MoreFilters')
```

Comment: it gives me an error element not found ( Unable to find visible button "MoreFilters" (Capybara::ElementNotFound))

Comment: @user8673269 I've added code that shows it works without the space,  I'm guessing you're not actually using a JS capable driver